# How can i import System.Windows in C#

Tags: c#, using

Hello i have copied this FFT implementation, but it says there is nothing like System.***Windows*** How can i make this code work? Allready got the answer I just wanted to edit this post so it is usefull now to somebody.

Source:
http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/an-fft-in-c/

Code::

```
using System;
using System.Net;


namespace FFT {

    public class FFT2 {
        // Element for linked list in which we store the
        // input/output data. We use a linked list because
        // for sequential access it's faster than array index.
        class FFTElement {
            public double re = 0.0;     // Real component
            public double im = 0.0;     // Imaginary component
            public FFTElement next;     // Next element in linked list
            public uint revTgt;         // Target position post bit-reversal
        }

        private uint m_logN = 0;        // log2 of FFT size
        private uint m_N = 0;           // FFT size
        private FFTElement[] m_X;       // Vector of linked list elements

        /**
         *
         */
        public FFT2() {
        }

        /**
         * Initialize class to perform FFT of specified size.
         *
         * @param   logN    Log2 of FFT length. e.g. for 512 pt FFT, logN = 9.
         */
        public void init(
            uint logN) {
            m_logN = logN;
            m_N = (uint)(1 << (int)m_logN);

            // Allocate elements for linked list of complex numbers.
            m_X = new FFTElement[m_N];
            for (uint k = 0; k < m_N; k++)
                m_X[k] = new FFTElement();

            // Set up "next" pointers.
            for (uint k = 0; k < m_N - 1; k++)
                m_X[k].next = m_X[k + 1];

            // Specify target for bit reversal re-ordering.
            for (uint k = 0; k < m_N; k++)
                m_X[k].revTgt = BitReverse(k, logN);
        }

        /**
         * Performs in-place complex FFT.
         *
         * @param   xRe     Real part of input/output
         * @param   xIm     Imaginary part of input/output
         * @param   inverse If true, do an inverse FFT
         */
        public void run(
            double[] xRe,
            double[] xIm,
            bool inverse = false) {
            uint numFlies = m_N >> 1;   // Number of butterflies per sub-FFT
            uint span = m_N >> 1;       // Width of the butterfly
            uint spacing = m_N;         // Distance between start of sub-FFTs
            uint wIndexStep = 1;        // Increment for twiddle table index

            // Copy data into linked complex number objects
            // If it's an IFFT, we divide by N while we're at it
            FFTElement x = m_X[0];
            uint k = 0;
            double scale = inverse ? 1.0 / m_N : 1.0;
            while (x != null) {
                x.re = scale * xRe[k];
                x.im = scale * xIm[k];
                x = x.next;
                k++;
            }

            // For each stage of the FFT
            for (uint stage = 0; stage < m_logN; stage++) {
                // Compute a multiplier factor for the "twiddle factors".
                // The twiddle factors are complex unit vectors spaced at
                // regular angular intervals. The angle by which the twiddle
                // factor advances depends on the FFT stage. In many FFT
                // implementations the twiddle factors are cached, but because
                // array lookup is relatively slow in C#, it's just
                // as fast to compute them on the fly.
                double wAngleInc = wIndexStep * 2.0 * Math.PI / m_N;
                if (inverse == false)
                    wAngleInc *= -1;
                double wMulRe = Math.Cos(wAngleInc);
                double wMulIm = Math.Sin(wAngleInc);

                for (uint start = 0; start < m_N; start += spacing) {
                    FFTElement xTop = m_X[start];
                    FFTElement xBot = m_X[start + span];

                    double wRe = 1.0;
                    double wIm = 0.0;

                    // For each butterfly in this stage
                    for (uint flyCount = 0; flyCount < numFlies; ++flyCount) {
                        // Get the top & bottom values
                        double xTopRe = xTop.re;
                        double xTopIm = xTop.im;
                        double xBotRe = xBot.re;
                        double xBotIm = xBot.im;

                        // Top branch of butterfly has addition
                        xTop.re = xTopRe + xBotRe;
                        xTop.im = xTopIm + xBotIm;

                        // Bottom branch of butterly has subtraction,
                        // followed by multiplication by twiddle factor
                        xBotRe = xTopRe - xBotRe;
                        xBotIm = xTopIm - xBotIm;
                        xBot.re = xBotRe * wRe - xBotIm * wIm;
                        xBot.im = xBotRe * wIm + xBotIm * wRe;

                        // Advance butterfly to next top & bottom positions
                        xTop = xTop.next;
                        xBot = xBot.next;

                        // Update the twiddle factor, via complex multiply
                        // by unit vector with the appropriate angle
                        // (wRe + j wIm) = (wRe + j wIm) x (wMulRe + j wMulIm)
                        double tRe = wRe;
                        wRe = wRe * wMulRe - wIm * wMulIm;
                        wIm = tRe * wMulIm + wIm * wMulRe;
                    }
                }

                numFlies >>= 1;     // Divide by 2 by right shift
                span >>= 1;
                spacing >>= 1;
                wIndexStep <<= 1;   // Multiply by 2 by left shift
            }

            // The algorithm leaves the result in a scrambled order.
            // Unscramble while copying values from the complex
            // linked list elements back to the input/output vectors.
            x = m_X[0];
            while (x != null) {
                uint target = x.revTgt;
                xRe[target] = x.re;
                xIm[target] = x.im;
                x = x.next;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Do bit reversal of specified number of places of an int
         * For example, 1101 bit-reversed is 1011
         *
         * @param   x       Number to be bit-reverse.
         * @param   numBits Number of bits in the number.
         */
        private uint BitReverse(
            uint x,
            uint numBits) {
            uint y = 0;
            for (uint i = 0; i < numBits; i++) {
                y <<= 1;
                y |= x & 0x0001;
                x >>= 1;
            }
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question, and post the **relevant** code here. Expecting people to leave this site in order to even figure out what you're asking is unreasonable. It also means that if the other site is not available for some reason, your question is meaningless, and it can't be searched by future users. Questions here should stand on their own and contain all necessary content so that they can be answered. (Just post the **relevant** part of the code, not a large wall of text.) Thanks.

Comment: Also I suggest not changing your question so drastically ('using System.Windows' to 'How can I test this FFT implementation'). If you have a separate problem you are trying to deal with, ask a separate question.

Comment: But i have poster everything earlier

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what your requirement is, or what errors you are getting

Comment: I am sorry I have edited it in like 50 seconds.

Comment: copying is ok if(!) you understand what and why. Don't expect to solve a problem, or consider it solved, by pasting

Comment: Just asking how to use it. I was using Pascal up to this time.

Comment: Using pascal... that's valid argument (no pun intended). Welcome to 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Windows` is the Windows Presentation Foundation namespace. The article is assuming you have a WPF application. If you don't have one, you can create one from Visual Studio from File > New Project > ... > Windows > WPF Application.

WPF is a way of creating graphical desktop applications for MS Windows. If you come from a command-line OS you may be more comfortable making a Windows Console application.

If you want to learn how to create a WPF application you need a [WPF tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Introduction-to-Building-b8d16419).